# php generated html table using ajax to apply user actions like delete, update and edit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm new to ajax and would like to use it with php to create a table that a user can edit in the front end of the webapp.

this is what i have so far...

PHP

```
class genTable{

  public function table1(){

    global $data;
    $result = $data->getData(); //from another class
    echo '<table class="table"> 
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Heading</td>
              </tr>';

    foreach($result as $res){
      echo '<tr><td>' . $res['Name'] . '</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';
  }

}
```

eventually i will just call that function to display it, is there a way to create a jquery function that uses ajax to add on three buttons update, edit and new that carry out their actions?

Comment: Two things, back-end & front-end. What you are doing is a back-end code generating front-end. You'll use Jquery AJAX on front-end, and need to make a call to a PHP page (back-end) that throw some data to AJAX handle and display it at current front-end. Start here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: This is an open-ended question. Try sharing some code you've cooked up yourself. Additionally, you can look at [**Editable DataTables**](http://datatables.net/examples/api/editable.html) using jquery to implement desired functionality.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do in such case is

```
foreach($result as $res){

    echo '<tr>'
    echo '<td>' . $res['Name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="#" onclick="UpdateUser('.$res['Name'].')">Update</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="#" onclick="EditUser('.$res['Name'].')">Edit</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="#" onclick="NewUser()">New</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';

}
```

Then I'd write those JavaScript functions which will receive `$res['Name']` (or ID ?) as parameter.

Those functions can then make ajax call when invoked for next action.